# Deleted apt sources.list file

Tags: 10.04, apt, software-sources

I accidentally deleted my `sources.list` file in the apt folder and now none of my apt commands are working. I tried to download the list again but couldn't find the link. I am using Ubuntu 10.04. Can someone tell me how to tackle the issue or can give me the download the lists again?

Comment: give code for http://mirrors.harvard.edu 10.04 LUCID UBUNTU sources.list

Answer (score 10):

There is a really useful website for that.

> http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/

Answer (score 4):

```
## The main officially supported repository
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates main restricted

## Unsupported open source software
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates universe

## Unsupported software of questonable license status (not open source)
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates multiverse

## Security updates repository
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security multiverse
```

You might also want to consider adding the following sections (but if you don't know what they are, it's probably better to stay away):

```
## The backports repository
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Canonical's partner repository
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid partner

## Medibuntu
deb http://packages.medibuntu.org/ lucid free non-free
deb-src http://packages.medibuntu.org/ lucid free non-free
```

Comment: This does not support 10.04 anymore

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sources.list file from a running server:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 10.04 LTS _Lucid Lynx_ - Release i386 (20100429)]/ lucid main restricted
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.

deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid main restricted
deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates main restricted
deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid universe
deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid universe
deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates universe
deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid multiverse
deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid multiverse
deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates multiverse
deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from the 'backports'
## repository.
## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security multiverse
```

Note that this list is using the Spanish servers. You should adjust it to your location.

Answer (score 2):

all the answers on this questions are outdated by now, which is logical.

If you're still using old release (Ubuntu < 12.04)and still want to get updates using apt-get use the following source.list file:

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric main
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric main
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates main
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates main
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric universe
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric universe
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates universe
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates universe
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric-security main
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric-security main
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric-security universe
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric-security universe
```

[src](https://coderwall.com/p/3n6xka/fix-apt-on-old-unsupported-ubuntu-releases)