# Impossible to install php5

Tags: php

I had php5 installed today, and, I don't remember how, but I guess it not installed anymore ...
When I try something like that:

```
aptitude install php5-cli
```

It tells me that no version of package php5-cli is available ...
I'm on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

It is in the repositories - http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/php5-cli

Check which repositories you have enabled.

Comment: How to enable a repository? I had just added the repositories in my sources.list ...

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#Adding_Repositories_in_Ubuntu Once you have checked the reopsitories, apt-get update and then install php5-cli

Comment: I had `deb http://packages.ubuntu.com/ lucid php5-cli` in my sources.list. But I have the same problem ...

Comment: That is not the proper syntax. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/143295/deleted-apt-sources-list-file